# Problem getting wifi connection broadcast event in android

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi

I am trying to implement an activity with a button that toggles wifi state on and off when clicked. Turning on and off works, but at the same time, I would like to change the colow or image of the button accordingly, ie, different image when on and different when off. TO do so, I have created an Intent Filter and a broadcast receiver function. In the broadcast receiver I am checking for several system events such as power connected/disconnected, battery change, wifi on/off, etc. The problem is that I do not receive messages for wifi state change - I do get battery and power related messages but not for wifi (PS. I have the same problem with bluetooth on/off notifications). Can anyone tell me what could be wrong? Here is the code:

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();

    intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON");
    intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF");
    intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW");
    intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY");
    intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED");
    intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED");
    intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED");
    intentFilter.addAction("WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION");
    intentFilter.addAction("BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF");
    intentFilter.addAction("BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON");

    registerReceiver(myReceiver, intentFilter);
}

private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String str = intent.getAction();

        displayMessage("In myReceiver, action = " + str);
        Log.d("Settings", "Received action: " + str);

        if (str.equals("android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED")) {
            displayMessage("battery changed...");
        } else if (str.equals("android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED")) {
            displayMessage("power connected");
        } else if (str.equals("android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED")) {
            displayMessage("power disconnected");
        } else if (str.equals("WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION")) {
            int wifiState = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN);
            displayMessage("wifi state is " + wifiState);               
        } else if (str.equals("BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON")) {
            displayMessage("bluetooth on");             
        } else if (str.equals("BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF")) {
            displayMessage("bluetooth off");
    }
}};
```

Comment: Do you use emulator or real device? WiFi and Bluetooth don't work in emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out another solution to this, since the default way does not seem to work out for me. What I do is the following:

On toggle Wifi button click, I first call wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(!enabled) and then I call a function that starts a thread and checks the wifiManager for a change of state. The thread runs until there is a change in the wifi state or 5 seconds have passed without any change. If the state is changed, I send a custom broadcast to the activity that notifies about this. This seems to work well, so I consider this issue recolved.

Answer (score 1):

Add **"android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"** instead of **"WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION"**, 
as there should be String constant, not the String code piece

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try looking for changes in the ConnectivityManager
 intentFilter.addAction ("ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION");